# jQuery Find Div within Parent

Tags: jquery

I'm not sure I worded this correctly. But I have an HTML document setup something similar to this.

```
<div id="intro_page" class="sub_page">

        <div class="sub_header"><img src="assets/img/intro_header.jpg" /></div>

        <div class="video_holder">
            <video class="video_player"></video>
        </div>

        <div class="page_text"><img src="" width="1020" /></div>


</div><!-- /intro_page -->
```

and

```
<div id="spark_page" class="sub_page car_page">

            <div class="sub_header"><img src="assets/img/header.jpg" /></div>

            <div class="video_holder">
                <video class="video_player"></video>
            </div>

            <ul class="car_story">
                <li data-text="story1_text"><img src="assets/img/story1_btn2.jpg" /></li>
                <li><img src="assets/img/story2_btn2.jpg" /></li>
                <li><img src="assets/img/story3_btn2.jpg" /></li>
            </ul>


            <div class="page_text"><img src="" width="1020" /></div>

</div><!-- /spark_page -->
```

I'm trying to target the `page_text` div if someone clicks on a `car_story li`. But because there are two divs that have `page_text`, I don't know how to target the one which is in the same parent div as the `car_story ul`. Hope this makes sense. Thanks!

I've tried things similar to this, but with no luck.

```
$(".car_story li").click(function() {

    $(this).parent().find(".page_text img").attr("src","newimage.jpg");

});
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Pass in the closest div.sub_page as the context in the selector, then the element you want to find

```
$(".car_story li").click(function() {
    var parent = $(this).closest('.sub_page'); // find closest sub_page
    $(".page_text img",parent).attr("src","newimage.jpg"); // find img inside of closest sub_page
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".car_story li").click(function() {
    $(this).parents("div").find(".page_text > img").attr("src","newimage.jpg");
});
```

Comment: Doesn't appear to be working for me. The image src isn't changing.

Comment: while that works, I'm looking for ways to use that same line of code for other div's that aren't necessarily the `#spark_page`

Comment: Ended up going with something close to yours, but you helped me in the right direction. Thanks! `$(this).parents(".sub_page").find(".page_text > img").attr("src","new_image.jpg");`

Comment: Just changed the code to acommodate your need for a more reusable code. Don't forget to accept the answer that helped you the most

Answer (score 1):

Try `closest()`

```
$(".car_story li").click(function() {

    $(this).closest('.sub_page').find(".page_text img")
                                .attr("src","newimage.jpg");

});
```

Answer (score 0):

This has the same result, but I think it is more clear as to what result you will get in all cases (for example if you had another page possibly ajaxed in that also happened to have a li with the car_story class then this click event will still only fire for the spark_page.):

```
$(".car_story li").click(function() {
    $('div#spark_page').find(".page_text img").attr("src","newimage.jpg");
});
```

Of course if you were to ajax in more html with li car_story s and wanted to change the source of all of the .page_text img then I think you could do

```
$(".car_story li").click(function() {
    $(".page_text img").attr("src","newimage.jpg");
});
```