# When link is pressed, how to hide a div using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, hide

I have a link (not a button I came across a solution on W3schools but that's using a button and I tried and it didn't work with link) and I want to hide the div using jquery when the link is pressed. Not sure where my error here is..

```
<body>
<script>
    $("a").click(function(){
    ("overlay").hide();
    });

</script>

<div class="overlay">
    <p><a href="#">Hello, world!</a></p>
</div>
```

Comment: not `("overlay").hide();` but `$(".overlay").hide();`

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is your selector. `$('overlay')` is looking for a tag named "overlay" when you want the class. `$('.overlay')` should work, instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("a").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parents("div.overlay").hide();
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/b7Ahc/)**

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$("a").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parents("div.overlay").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest('div.overlay').hide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Or try this:

```
$("a").click(function() {
    (".overlay").hide();
});
```

You were missing a `.`

Comment: this is not working for some reason, none of these are actually, could there be something in my css stopping it from working?

Answer (score 0):

Minor errors $ missing before ("overlay").hide(); and missing document.ready

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("a").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $(".overlay").hide();
  });
});
```

use event.preventDefault() to about page popping on the click of the link.

Comment: Hey Mayank, you did miss again the class selector $(".overlay").hide();

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a','.overlay').click(function(){
    $('.overlay').hide();
    return false; //stops browser from triggering link
    //another method is var.preventDefault(); Someone else can explain the difference lol
});
```

the second parameter of the jQuery selector is a sort of parent selector. Selects the anchor within the `.overlay`

Comment: not working, could there be something else preventing it from hiding?

Comment: @user3308129 ahhh the link is triggering. Add a `return false;` line. I'll edit my answer

Comment: Hey Beneto: You wrote: " the second parameter of the jQuery selector is a sort of parent selector. Selects the anchor within the .overlay " - this is not right, what you meant is $('.overlay a')...

Comment: @ddlab that's another way of doing it. Essentially that's the child way. `$('.overlay a')`, `$('a','.overlay')` and `$('.overlay>a')` work the same way. They have their unique differences in selecting elements. I just prefer that method of child selection

Comment: @Beneto: Don´t agree. $('a','.overlay').click(function(){... adds the click function to 'a' AND '.overlay' whithout any difference, if they are children or parents or whatever.

Comment: @ddlab No to add multiple elements to the addEventListener it's `$('a,h1,.overlay')`. Say you had two forms with different name and you wanted to select all the input's of one particular form. `$('input[type="text"]','form[name="form1"]').css({'background':'red'});`. Agreed you can write it this way: `$('form[name="form1"]>input[type="text"]')`.

Comment: @ddlab here's a link where someone else uses an example. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13364592/jquery-find-div-within-parent

Comment: @Beneto: OK, didn't know that. Will tryout it. Until now I thought that $('a','b') should be the same as $('a,b') ... never too late to learn :-)

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the preventDefault for the link. It's href is "#" which will not take you anywhere when the link is pressed.

You're only problem user3308129 is that you didn't include a period (".") before the class name and a dollar sign before the jQuery call.

See the code below for corrections:

```
$("a").click(function(){
    $(".overlay").hide();
});
```